# How to build dynamic enums in Rails 6 model concerns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, activesupport-concern

I'm trying to build a `Bookable` model concern that adds an enum to the including model, that's used for tracking the stage of the booking:

```rb
module Bookable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  STAGES = {
    confirmed: 0,
    completed: 1,
    cancelled: 2,
    issue_raised: 3
  }.freeze

  included do
    enum stage: STAGES.merge(self.extra_stages)

    belongs_to :customer
    belongs_to :provider
    validates :stage, presence: true

    def self.extra_stages
      {}
    end
  end
end
```

The `STAGES` constant defines available stages, however I want including models to be able to add stages that are specific to them, by overriding the `self.extra_stages` method. For example, in a `Mission` model:

```rb
class Mission < ApplicationRecord
  include Bookable

  def self.extra_stages
    {
      awaiting_estimate: 4,
      awaiting_payment: 5,
      awaiting_report: 6,
      report_sent: 7
    }
  end
end
```

However, this code fails:

```sh
$ bundle exec rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.2.2)
[1] pry(main)> Mission.stages
NoMethodError: undefined method `extra_stages' for Mission (call 'Mission.connection' to establish a connection):Class
Did you mean?  extract_associated
from /home/gueorgui/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
```

Any clue as to what I might be doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `included` is a hook that is evaluated after `include Booking`. In that case `Missing.extra_stages` is not defined. In your case you can put `include Booking` after the method.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to arrive to my solution (which I will share below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are cleaner ways to do what I'm about to present, but it will accomplish what you're trying to do. Mind the brevity (I removed your associations to do a quick spot-check on my machine):

```rb
module Bookable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do 
    STAGES = {
      confirmed: 0,
      completed: 1,
      cancelled: 2,
      issue_raised: 3
    }.freeze
  end 
end

class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base 
  self.abstract_class = true 

  def self.acts_as_bookable_with(extra_stages = {})
    include Bookable

    enum stage: self::STAGES.merge(extra_stages)
  end
end 

class Mission < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_bookable_with({
      awaiting_estimate: 4,
      awaiting_payment: 5,
      awaiting_report: 6,
      report_sent: 7
    })
end
```

If you want to define these on the class, it would look like this:

```rb
module Bookable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do 
    STAGES = {
      confirmed: 0,
      completed: 1,
      cancelled: 2,
      issue_raised: 3
    }.freeze
  end 
end

class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base 
  self.abstract_class = true 

  def self.acts_as_bookable_with(extra_stages)
    include Bookable
    if extra_stages.is_a?(Symbol)
      extra_stages = self.send(extra_stages)
    elsif extra_stages.is_a?(Hash)
      # do nothing
    else
      raise TypeError, "can't find extra_stages from #{extra_stages.inspect}"
    end
    stages = self::STAGES.merge(extra_stages)
    enum stage: stages
  end
end 

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  def self.extra_stages
    {
      awaiting_estimate: 4,
      awaiting_payment: 5,
      awaiting_report: 6,
      report_sent: 7
    }
  end

  acts_as_bookable_with(:extra_stages)

end
```

Note that we're calling `acts_as_bookable_with` after we define our class method. Otherwise, we'll get undefined method error.

There isn't a whole lot of "bad" in having this in ApplicationRecord. It's not the most ideal way of doing it, but most of these `acts_as_*` modules follow this exact pattern anyway and inject into `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to yzalavin pointing me in the right direction (the fact that `included` is a hook that's evaluated after `include Bookable`), I've arrived to this solution, which works in a way I'm happy with:

```rb
module Bookable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  STAGES = {
    confirmed: 0,
    completed: 1,
    cancelled: 2,
    issue_raised: 3
  }.freeze

  included do |base|
    enum stage: STAGES.merge(base.extra_stages)

    belongs_to :customer
    belongs_to :provider
    validates :stage, presence: true
  end

  class_methods do
    def extra_stages
      return {} unless defined? self::EXTRA_STAGES

      self::EXTRA_STAGES
    end
  end
end
```

And in the including model:

```rb
class Mission < ApplicationRecord
  EXTRA_STAGES = {
    awaiting_estimate: 4,
    awaiting_payment: 5,
    awaiting_report: 6,
    report_sent: 7
  }.freeze

  include Bookable

  # (...)
end
```

I would welcome any improvements upon this solution, as it still feels like it could be simplified.